# Linq query where clause to include the UTC Timezone conversion

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I have a DB in Azure SQL Server where I have to compare the Date field against the current Eastern zone time, the SQL query where clause is like below

```
where CAST(getdate() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' as date) = mo.orderdate
```

Where current datetime in the Azure SQL DB is converted in to the EST time. I am not sure how I can convert above query to the linq query so I can use it in the C# like below

```
 where mo.orderdate ==  CAST(getdate() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' as date)
```

but this doent work and errors

Comment: `CAST(getdate() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' as date)` is probably better as `CAST(SYSUTCDATETIME() AT TIME ZONE 'Eastern Standard Time' as date)`

Answer (score 0):

My bad as I was do the UTC conversion directly in the Query. I tried like below

```
        var timeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var easternZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");
        var todayDt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(timeUtc, easternZone);
```

and used the `todayDt` in the where clause

```
where mo.OrderDate.Date == todayDt.Date
```